# How do we use a Lookup table in Mule DataWeave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I would like to know how we can define our customer LookUpTable in DataWeave.

I am not able to find options to define custom LookUpTable

I am looking for some lookup options like how we do it in DataMapper as below

[image]

Can Someone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

What kind of custom LookUpTable are you trying to do? Have a look at the [data weave docs section 13.3.1](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave#_existing_functions)  which explains how to call external flows, this may help.

Comment: I have enhanced my question ..I am Looking for more of a lookup Table . Let me know how to use another flow lookup for the lookup table that you do it within mule as you do it in DataMapper

Comment: did you find any clue how to use UserDefinedLookupTable in dataweaver?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below url's might be helpful- first link explains the way where datamapper used to have ( where in datamapper itself in table format you have defined the custom datas whereas in dataweave  externally create .csv or .txt for lookup and refer it via scripts

https://gandham38.wordpress.com/2016/08/19/dataweave-lookup-example/

[Custom Lookup in dataweave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573711/custom-lookup-in-dataweave)

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/59409/how-to-properly-use-the-dataweave-lookup-function.html