# Custom Lookup in dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I have 2 field in the input, one is primary_language & the other is secondary_language. I have a case where I have to lookup values present in these two fields and then return a specific value according to the table.
For example
If primary language is English & secondary language is null then English will be the output & if primary language is Spanish & secondary is Sign then put None in the output & so on. Can one tell how we can perform this in dataweave in mulesoft.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have some more dynamic logic or its just the two conditions you mentioned above?

you can use when/otherwise or call another flow to get the value.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

---
{
language: 'English' when (payload.primary == 'English' and payload.secondary is :null) 
                otherwise ('None' when payload.primary == 'Spanish' and payload.secondary == 'Sign'
                    otherwise ''
                ),

language2: lookup("testFlow",payload)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Manik Magar, I used another approach for this so not sure if this will work. I have another similar question, I am creating an xml in output in one Dataweave of which i need to lookup a value for a field say "Status" from another flow & output of dataweave (by declaring variable in this data weave to convert input status in some fixed format). I am putting fund-status: lookup("Test",payload) & in a "Test" flow I am putting this
%output application/java
%var STATUS = {"Com" : "COMPLETE","Ref" : "REFUND"}
---
{fund-status: flowVars.XYZ.status}. But i get Cannot coerce object to string.

Comment: @Hemant, if this is different question, could you please open a new question and add config's if possible, so that we can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create another flow which performs this lookup for you (potentially you could do a database call, or something else like a groovy script), and store your values and what you expect to get returned based on those values.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#expressions-that-call-external-flows covers this concept a little bit, but the general idea is the following:

```
language: lookup("myLookupFlow", payload)
```

Then, all you need to do is query your dataset based on primary and secondary, and you will get your "transformed" value back.